# What are the valid country codes available for the windows 'net user' command?

Tags: windows, shell, cultureinfo, culture, windows-scripting

I have a Windows script that creates a user using 'net user'.  I need to ensure that this user is created with US-English countrycode even when run on a Japanese OS. The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771865(v=ws.11)) suggests there is a 3-digit code required for this but nowhere can I find an example or list of what the valid codes are.  I've tried 840, 409 and 1033 - all give the error "An illegal country/region code has been supplied."  Any ideas?

`net user testUser testPwd123 /add /countrycode:840`

Comment: So I've found that countrycode of 001 (or just 1) is for the United States but it didn't solve my issue with Japanese output in the cmd.exe window when Japanese is the default language of the OS. I ended up having to change the code page with 'chcp 437' in the scripts used by testUser in order to get English output.  

The countrycode 001 (or 000, 002, 003) can be confirmed by executing:  
`net user testUser testPwd123 /add /countrycode:nnn`  
`net user testUser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation of the country code is actually implemented by `NET USER` command. The underlying [`NetUserSetInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netusersetinfo) API will allow you to set whatever country code number you like. If you set the country code to a number which `NET USER` doesn't recognise, it displays the country as `(null)`.

The `NetUserSetInfo` API has separate country code and code page fields. You can set the country code using [`USER_INFO_1024`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/ns-lmaccess-user_info_1024) and the code page using [`USER_INFO_1025`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/ns-lmaccess-user_info_1025). However, the `NET USER` command appears to only know about the country code and offers no way to set or display the code page. Furthermore, if I create a new user and SSH to it, the user's code page setting appears to make no difference to the code page displayed by the `CHCP` command.

The `NET USER` country codes actually derive from MS-DOS and OS/2. They are based on a subset of international dialling codes with some modifications. They ultimately date back to the `COUNTRY=` statement in MS-DOS `CONFIG.SYS`

I doubt that Windows currently does anything with these codes. I think they are actually a left-over from the support of MS-DOS and OS/2 clients which was included in earlier versions of Windows. The `NET` command is a part of Windows which historically descends from IBM/Microsoft LAN Manager for MS-DOS and OS/2. The fact that the list of supported country codes is so restrictive is a sign of the fact that this is a disused historical vestige – if this setting was actually used for anything any more, there would be demand for adding a broader range of supported values.

Here are the supported values (in Windows 10 version 2004, but I expect far older versions of Windows will produce the same results):

| Country Code | Country |
| --- | --- |
| 000 | System Default |
| 001 | United States |
| 002 | Canada (French) |
| 003 | Latin America |
| 031 | Netherlands |
| 032 | Belgium |
| 033 | France |
| 034 | Spain |
| 039 | Italy |
| 041 | Switzerland |
| 044 | United Kingdom |
| 045 | Denmark |
| 046 | Sweden |
| 047 | Norway |
| 049 | Germany |
| 061 | Australia |
| 081 | Japan |
| 082 | Korea |
| 086 | China (PRC) |
| 088 | Taiwan |
| 099 | Asia |
| 351 | Portugal |
| 358 | Finland |
| 785 | Arabic |
| 972 | Hebrew |

Here is a Windows batch file I used to produce the above list:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
rem Make sure we are using Windows commands not Cygwin/etc if you happen to have Cygwin first in PATH
PATH %systemroot%\system32
NET USER DELETEME myCmplxPwd1! /ADD 1>NUL: 2>NUL:
echo. >NETUSER.TMP
FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,999) DO (
        NET USER DELETEME /COUNTRYCODE:%%i 1>NUL: 2>NUL:
        NET USER DELETEME | findstr Country >> NETUSER.TMP
)
net user deleteme /delete 1>NUL: 2>NUL:
type netuser.tmp | sort /unique
del netuser.tmp
```

Comment: Thank you for all the info and the nice script to work with @Simon Kissane.

Comment: Note that these country codes are equal to the [international phone country codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes):
- +1 US
- +44 UK
- +358 Finland

Comment: @ErikBachmann Yes. I should point out my answer already stated that: "They are based on a subset of international dialling codes with some modifications". Also, +1 isn't just the US, +1 is the entire North American Numbering Plan, including Canada and some Caribbean countries. And some of these codes don't correspond to phone country codes at all, e.g. 002 ("Canada (French)"), 785 ("Arabic"– +7 is Russia), 003 ("Latin America"–Latin American countries are mostly +5x, while +3x codes are Europe)